# Hiding Menu items without inflating Menu layout

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I used to do this:

```
menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");

            android.view.MenuItem Edit = menu.findItem(R.id.edit);
            android.view.MenuItem Delete = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);

            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

            int position = info.position;
            ListView lv = (ListView) v;
            int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View rowView = lv.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);

            if (Rateit.isUserLoggedIn == true) {
                 {

                    Edit.setVisible(true);
                    Delete.setVisible(true);

                } else {
                    Edit.setVisible(false);
                    Delete.setVisible(false);
                }
            } else {
                Edit.setVisible(false);
                Delete.setVisible(false);
            }
```

Now menu is set up by NOT inflating layout, but this:

```
menu.add(2, 1, 0, "Edit");
menu.add(2, 2, 0, "Delete");
```

However, I can't find the method I need to assign the `itemId` (second parameter in `add` method) to `Edit` / `Delete` so I can set them visible or not?  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`menu.add` returns a `MenuItem` if you save that into a variable you can then change the visibility of of them menu, for example

```
MenuItem edit = menu.add(2, 1, 0, "Edit");
MenuItem delete = menu.add(2, 2, 0, "Delete");
edit.setVisible(Rateit.isUserLoggedIn);
delete.setVisible(Rateit.isUserLoggedIn);
```

you could also just chain the calls together if you dont need to access the menu item later

```
menu.add(2, 1, 0, "Edit").setVisible(Rateit.isUserLoggedIn);
menu.add(2, 2, 0, "Delete").setVisible(Rateit.isUserLoggedIn);
```

Comment: Oh snap that was easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`add()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) returns a MenuItem, simply save this value to show / hide it whenever you want.

```
MenuItem edit = menu.add(2, 1, 0, "Edit");
// Do with "edit" as you please
```

Also please read about [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which states that variables, like `edit`, should start with lower case letters.

Comment: Yes, thanks on the Lower Case.  I am in the process of changing all that. I'm a newb, I know.  Selected the other answer, but marked you up on that fair reminder.